# Failed to notify spy hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy: java.io.IOException: Backing channel is disconnected

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, integration-testing

Observing below error while trying to execute below maven command in a Multi module Java project.

```
-DargLine="-DDB_SERVER=localhost -DDB_PORT=1234 -DDB_USER=Project -DDB_PASSWORD=password -DDB_NAME=account -DDB_MAX_POOL=10" clean install
```

**Error Logs-**

All the other modules have run successfully except the last one with below error. Not able to trace where exactly is the issue.

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20:verify (integration-tests) @ module ---
New build name is '22-08-2017-2396'
channel stopped
[ERROR] There are test failures.
Variable with name 'BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME' already exists, current value: '22-08-2017-2396', new value: '22-08-2017-2396'

Please refer to /Users/sonata-project/.jenkins/jobs/project/jobs/account/jobs/account-Build/workspace/module/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Build was aborted
Command was /bin/sh -c cd /Users/sonata-project/.jenkins/jobs/project/jobs/account/jobs/account-Build/workspace/module && /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -DDB_SERVER=localhost -DDB_PORT=1234 -DDB_USER=project -DDB_PASSWORD=project -DDB_NAME=account -DDB_MAX_POOL=10 -jar /Users/sonata-project/.jenkins/jobs/project/jobs/account/jobs/account-Build/workspace/module/target/surefire/surefirebooter218787093229383209.jar /Users/sonata-project/.jenkins/jobs/project/jobs/account/jobs/account-Build/workspace/module/target/surefire 2017-08-22T15-25-45_696-jvmRun1 surefire8248882233694904397tmp surefire_14269084166200557850tmp

Error while executing forked tests.Error while executing external command, process killed.org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineTimeOutException: Error while executing external command, process killed.

    org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:396)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineUtils$1.call(CommandLineUtils.java:260)
    ... 40 more
Fatal Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Flakes: 0, Elapsed timeout: false
Crashed tests:
com.project.test.client.ApplicationIT
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:679)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
Aborted by Kalyan Bire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:626)
    ... 39 more

[WARNING] Failed to notify spy hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy: java.io.IOException: Backing channel is disconnected.
```